# WebAuthN and BouncyCastle in .Net

Tags: .net, bouncycastle, ecdsa, webauthn

I am working on a proof of concept for YubiKey and webAuthN; I think I have the basic steps down, but I'm having some  issues verifying the signature;

there are a couple of places where this may be going wrong for me:

1)  When I do a "navigator.credentials.create" i get the credential object which I send to the server.

2)  On the server I get the COSE public Key;   which has a X and Y point (this is Elliptical Curve Encryption)

3)   I convert the X and Y (32 Bytes Uint8Array) to Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger
***One issue I have here*** is sometimes these X and Y coordinates produce NEGATIVE BigInteger (leftmost Bit is set)
I read that this means this is "leading" zero Byte, i.e. a 33 Byte Array, with Byte 0 as "0" - not sure if this is true, but couldn't find another instructions on this situation where the first bit is set

4)  I get the assertion from the "navigator.credentials.get" and send it to the server

5)  I use the X and Y from the previous step to build a Public Key,

6)  I use Base64Decode to decode the clientDataJSON and authenticatorData from the assertion to respective ByteArrays

7)  I Hash the "clientDataJSON" element using SHA256

8)  I build a byte array containing the raw "authenticatorData" and the Hashed "clientDataJSON" (concatenated)

9)  I use Base64Decode to decode the Signature element from the Assertion

10)  I Create a Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers.ECDsaSigner using the Public Key from above

11)  I Use VerifySignature over the concatenated authenticatorData and ClientDataHash.

This ALWAYS returns "FALSE" (i.e. bad signature)

Here is some relevant code:

```
//Load the Base64 Encoded ByteArrays for the PublicKey X and Y (stored when registered)
Dim EncryptionX as Byte() = Base64Decode(SavedPublicKey.X)
Dim EncryptionY as Byte() = Base64Decode(SavedPublicKey.Y)


//Decode signature and AuthenticatorData elements from assertion
Dim Signature as Byte() = Base64Decode(Assertion.Signature)
Dim authenticatorData as Byte() = Base64Decode(Assertion.authenticatorData)


//Decode and HASH ClientDataJson element form assertion
Dim ClientDataJson as Byte() = Base64Decode(Assertion.ClientDataJson)
Dim shaHash = SHA256.Create
Dim ClientDataHash As Byte() = shaHash.ComputeHash(ClientDataJson)

//Concatenate the AuthenticatorData and ClientDataHash
Dim CombinedMessage as List(Of Byte)
CombinedMessage.AddRange(authenticatorData)
CombinedMessage.AddRange(ClientDataHash)
Dim MessageToValidate as Byte()=CombinedMessage.ToArray()


//Get the secp256r1 Curve (I think this is the correct curve for WebAuthN
Dim x9ecpPar As Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X9.X9ECParameters = Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Sec.SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256r1")

Dim ECCcurve As Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECCurve = x9ecpPar.Curve

//build the "point" form the curve and the X and Y points
Dim Q As Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint = ECCcurve.CreatePoint(New Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(EncryptionX), New Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(EncryptionY))

//Build the Public Keys from the "Q" point using ECDSA algorthim 
Dim PublicKey As Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECPublicKeyParameters = New Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECPublicKeyParameters("ECDSA", Q, Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Sec.SecObjectIdentifiers.SecP256r1)


//Get an ANS1 Input stream from the Signature ByteArray
Dim ASN1 = New Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1InputStream(Signature)


Dim Sequence As Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1Sequence = ASN1.ReadObject()

Dim eR As Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger = DirectCast(Sequence(0), Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger).PositiveValue

Dim eS As Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger = DirectCast(seq(1), Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger).PositiveValue

Dim signer As Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers.ECDsaSigner = New Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers.ECDsaSigner

signer.Init(False, PublicKey)
Dim SignatureGood As Boolean = signer.VerifySignature(MessageToValidate, er, es)


//**** SignatureGood  ALWAYS False *****
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Having originally intended to go deep (as you have) into WebAuthn I ended up just pivoting and using (and contributing to) this excellent project (https://github.com/abergs/fido2-net-lib) instead. At the very least it will have code you can refer to.

I'd probably start here: https://github.com/abergs/fido2-net-lib/blob/master/Src/Fido2/Objects/CredentialPublicKey.cs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion;  I did look at that, but it uses .net core, and this project is for a MFA .dll in ADFS 3.0;  I don't think it supports .net core.

But I will try and get that Library to work; maybe I can make something of it.

Comment: Hopefully it can serve as a good reference implementation at least. Good luck!